# Two step authentication in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, authentication, rsa

Is it possible to implement two step authentication in Rails using Google's android application [Google Authenticator](http://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/)?

I want to implement two step verification similar to [dropbox](https://blog.dropbox.com/index.php/another-layer-of-security-for-your-dropbox-account/). They use Google Authenticator as well.

Is there any example code/application in rails?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A little googling has revealed a gem extension to devise that does this

https://github.com/AsteriskLabs/devise_google_authenticator

Or there's a blog post giving hints on how to roll your own

https://moocode.com/posts/5-simple-two-factor-ssh-authentication-with-google-authenticator

Answer (score 4):

ActiveModel::Otp  makes adding Two Factor Authentication(TFA) to a model simple https://github.com/heapsource/active_model_otp

Answer (score 0):

I think this gem is way better since it's extendable. One can setup backup codes if you need.

[Tinfoil Two factor](https://github.com/tinfoil/devise-two-factor)